# How are aircraft filmed in sky?

Tags: aircraft-operations

We have several spectacular and amazing [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=airplane%20in%20sky) of aircraft, flying high in the sky.  How are these videos filmed, at great altitudes?

Comment: they use a slingshot to launch the camera at the aircraft and they hope to get a nice shot (pun intended).

Comment: With a long selfie stick ;)

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/64241/15281

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two words: chase planes.

A few more words: The easiest way to film an airplane in flight is with another airplane in flight. [Here's one article on how that's done](http://www.airlinereporter.com/2012/09/chasing-lans-boeing-787-dreamliner-with-aeroial-photographers-of-wolfe-air/), including images captured from both sides; the chase plane (a Learjet 25B) getting the shots of the 787 Dreamliner, and crew aboard the Dreamliner getting a few snapshots of the chase plane.

[image]
[image]

Early shots taken from chase planes often used simple handheld cameras; a two-seater would normally be used with the pilot in front and the photographer in back. This is still a totally viable way to do it, but more modern professional shoots utilize aircraft specifically modified for the task by adding internal or external camera mounts, optical-quality viewports, etc. Here's a modified T-33 used by Boeing specifically for air-to-air photography, including some of the initial publicity shots of the 787 in flight; notice the camera mount between the seats that can be used by the GIB (he's using a handheld in this photo:

[image]

For lower-speed shots, you can also use a helicopter. Many of these such as news choppers have remote-control cameras on gyro-stabilized mounts, so the vibration of the airframe is minimized in the shot even at high zoom:

[image]

These same camera systems can be used for air-to-air shots as well, however the maximum airspeed of the helicopter becomes a limiting factor. Still great for publicity shots of small prop planes, or takeoffs/landings.

Comment: And then there is third airplane in flight to do behind the scenes.

Comment: That helicopter looks like it's smoking a pipe.

Answer (score 5):

I film all [my stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqNlFbviMwA) (from inside the plane) with a [GoPro](http://shop.gopro.com/cameras?gclid=Cj0KEQjwn86sBRDroPiR0LrSzNYBEiQAzOaSYAjuwIfECB_OCFMdidWLegB7BJOCO-IuWApZG06wjOsaAj8d8P8HAQ). This seems to be the common way the smaller guys are doing it. There are companies that make mounts that will even hold the camera on [outside a plane](http://www.rammount.com/reviews/goprohdmountedairplane). You can check out [this post](http://sportys.tumblr.com/post/42926333172/gopro-quick-start-guide-for-pilots) from Sporty's on the matter.  Some of the stuff shot by the pros may be taken from another plane or a helicopter. The news choppers I see leaving from KPNE have the newer nose style cameras that I assume they operate from the inside of the chopper.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific in your question, so there are many ways that aerial footage can be captured.

[As Dave mentions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16489/1696), GoPro cameras have gained popularity especially with private pilots. They are relatively cheap, small, easy to use, and capture good quality video. Many videos from [inside the cockpit](https://youtu.be/8aoXSE5mUHw) or [outside](https://youtu.be/6Du513WwUmg) use cameras like these.

Air to air footage is taken from other aircraft. For the most flexibility, a [fighter jet](https://youtu.be/ky67166frag) is a [good choice](http://www.imaging-resource.com/news/2014/07/10/dream-job-being-the-official-photographer-of-the-us-air-force-thunderbirds). You could also shoot through the door of a [smaller aircraft](https://youtu.be/Hcy37lmQpg0). Helicopters are best at lower altitudes and speeds but are good for filming [takeoffs and landings](https://youtu.be/gI4jWYZLeHQ).