# How in-flight close-ups are captured

Tags: plane-spotting

What equipment and preparations are necessary to shot a picture like this (an in-flight close-up, clearly shot over a large body of water, possibly from a short distance):

[image]

This question is somewhat similar to [my question asked at Travel half a year ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64235/15281). But, in that picture plane was captured during final approach, over a city, supposed from some building (actually turned out to be shot from a helicopter).

I assume that using a telescope or shotting from any building won't help much in shooting such picture as above. If not, then what? A drone? Again, a helicopter?

Comment: From the perspective you can see the only possibility is being above the aircraft, not on the ground. I wouldn't be surprised this is a 3D synthetic rendering, as the reflection on the nose is quite unnatural ([anisotropic](http://www.neilblevins.com/cg_education/aniso_ref_real_world/aniso_ref_real_world.htm)) for paint.

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/how-are-aircraft-filmed-in-sky

Comment: It could also be a doctored image, with the aircraft photographed and the background added later.

Comment: @mins to me is quite a natural image shot with a telephoto lens

Comment: @mins and Jamiec: As per my knowledge, the image is as natural as can be and it is neither rendered nor modified in anyway. However, as per Federico cite of related question, my questions seems to be a dupe.

Comment: @Federico: I was referring to the dry paint reflection, which is normally [more diffuse](http://imgproc.airliners.net/photos/airliners/7/0/4/0472407-v40-10.jpg), but I agree that without a less compressed image, it's difficult to say (neat [reflection from 3D](http://vibamo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/vibamo_350_01_0018__.jpg) rendering)

Comment: @mins On the other hand it is hard to not agree with you that this reflection looks a little bit artificial / unnatural.